# Why is 1st string in string array ignored

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader

I wrote a program, that doesn't behave as expected. Code below is supposed to find equal strings from text file and array and display it in console

Array :

```
public static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    static
    {
        words.add("should");
        words.add("find");
        words.add("matches");
    }
```

Reading from the txt file data like that `find smth must apple sun matches` and splitting into particular words

```
while(fileReader.ready())
        {
            String [] rowdata = fileReader.readLine().split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i < rowdata.length; i++)
        {
            cand = rowdata[i];


            for(int j=0; j < words.size(); j++)
            {
                cand1 = words.get(j);

                if(cand.equals(cand1))
                {
                    System.out.println(cand);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected output :

```
find matches
```

Real output :

```
matches
```

Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me.  Have you tried stepping through it?  The problem could be how you're reading the file, or the file itself.

Comment: Yes, i've tried. Although firstly it takes"find" and try to compare it with "find", the result of this comparison is false :(

Comment: Just some suggestions. Use trim() on strings after split. Use trywithresource when reading file or make sure that you are closing your file.

Comment: Can you try to compare like `cand.trim().equals(cand1)`?

Comment: @Kurlik Kurlikovi4 If it returned false, there must have been some difference.  Can you paste the file into your question?

Comment: If i add one space before the string `find smth must apple sun matches`, just before "find", it works properly

Comment: @KurlikKurlikovi4 Are you sure that in your file you have actual word "find"? I mean is there no some weird character that e.g. only looks like "i"? Otherwise... File encoding?

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak Yes, i am sure. To ensure, i've even copied this word from words list and pasted in txt file... According to NotePad, UTF-8

Comment: Finally found out. Instead of UTF-8 i should use ANSI. Thanks you, guys